# Building Decision Tree on a high dimensional data set with sparse Boolean values

Tags: cart, unbalanced-classes, sparse

I have been trying to learn a decision tree on a data-set with almost 400 features. The target variable has only two values and the data is highly skewed towards the non-event class (90 % of the data set).

All the features take only Boolean values. The decision tree plots are skewed towards the non event class. I am looking for the path that helps me predict the event class. 
I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere. Can anyone give me some ideas?

**EDIT**:

*Apologies if the question wasn't clear. I just started as a Data Science inter, and this is my first project*.

The decision tree predicts almost all the non-event class (90% of the data) with high accuracy, whereas almost entirely misclassifies the event class.

What do I need to do to build the tree that predicts the non-event class with high accuracy and to see the decision paths that makes up such a tree?

I tried ensemble methods but it only improved my classifier marginally

Comment: Decision trees will work just fine.  Try boosting or bagging to deal with the unbalanced classes.  The model you train will output a score for each class; try different thresholds on these scores to obtain reasonable sensitivity and specificity values.

Comment: Why is the fact that the decision tree skews in the same way as the data a problem? It ought to do so! If it didn't it would be making a lot of wrong classifications.

Comment: Try to select the model parameters in a way that is dependent on the metric that is sensitive even to small predicted label changes. You might want to take a look at optimization of area under the curve (AUC) for ROC curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarification of the problem**

To clarify the OP's problem, as I read it (and your edit makes this more clear): Given a dataset with 10% events and 90% nonevents, a naive classifier could obtain 90% accuracy simply by choosing the 'nonevent' outcome every single iteration.

Tree-based algorithms (as well as other types of classifiers) can easily fall into this minimization 'mistake' because the algorithm is designed to treat all errors as equal; in many real-world situations, this is simply not acceptable, and one may prefer an algorithm that makes proportionally more false-alarm errors in order to improve the detection rate. 90% vs. 10% is actually a fairly benign example of this problem, in many real world cases the ratio is much worse.

**Possible solutions**

The two common ways to deal with this problem are:

1) Sampling. For each training step, either a) over-sample the underrepresented class, or b) under-sample the overrepresented class.

2) Error-weighting. Penalize misses of the event (model says "no event" when there is one) more than false alarms (model says "event" when there is no event).

Different packages that implement tree-based classification often implement one or both of these approaches out of the box.